# WPF/C#5.0 Publish/Subscribe to an array of static fields?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, static, c#-5.0

Using C# 5.0, I'm creating a publish/subscribe relationship on a static field, so that I can access it from multiple pages. In the host window, I have

```
public enum PLCStates
    {
        Good,
        Bad,
        Disabled
    };
    public static class PLCSafeStates
    {
        public static event EventHandler testStates1Changed;
        private static PLCStates _testStates1;

        public static PLCStates testStates1 
        {
        get { return _testStates1; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _testStates1)
                {
                    _testStates1 = value;
                    if (testStates1Changed != null)
                        testStates1Changed(null, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And then in the pages hosted by the window, I have things like:

```
public FB1()
{
InitializeComponent();
SafteyFaults.PLCSafeStates.testStates1Changed += PLCSafeStates_testStates1Changed;
        }

    private void PLCSafeStates_testStates1Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    var test2 = SafteyFaults.PLCSafeStates.testStates1;
    if (test2 == SafteyFaults.PLCStates.Bad)
        {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnFB, "PLCBad", true);

        }
    if (test2 == SafteyFaults.PLCStates.Good)
        {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnFB, "PLCGood", false);
        }

    }

    private void btnFB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnOut1, "PLCBad",false);
        if (SafteyFaults.PLCSafeStates.testStates1 == SafteyFaults.PLCStates.Good)
        SafteyFaults.PLCSafeStates.testStates1=SafteyFaults.PLCStates.Bad;
        else
        SafteyFaults.PLCSafeStates.testStates1 = SafteyFaults.PLCStates.Good;

    }
```

(right now, I don't have any business logic wired up yet- once I get this working, I'll link to actual data).

Anyhow, all of this works to create a single field I can subscribe to, modify, etc. But I need 20+ of these fields. I want to make 'testStates1' an array, but I've not been able to get it to work.

If I make the following edits to the code shown so far, it compiles and runs, but throws an error when I actually try to access the field (e.g. click on the button to change it):

```
 //window
         public static class PLCSafeStates
     {
        public static event EventHandler testStates1Changed;
        private static PLCStates[] _testStates1;

        public static PLCStates[] testStates1 
        {
        get { return _testStates1; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _testStates1)
                {
                    _testStates1 = value;
                    if (testStates1Changed != null)
                        testStates1Changed(null, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
    }

//page
        public FB1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        SafteyFaults.PLCSafeStates.testStates1Changed += PLCSafeStates_testStates1Changed;
        }

    private void PLCSafeStates_testStates1Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    var test2 = SafteyFaults.PLCSafeStates.testStates1[0];
    if (test2 == SafteyFaults.PLCStates.Bad)
        {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnFB, "PLCBad", true);

        }
    if (test2 == SafteyFaults.PLCStates.Good)
        {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnFB, "PLCGood", false);
        }

    }

    private void btnFB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnOut1, "PLCBad",false);
        if (SafteyFaults.PLCSafeStates.testStates1[0] == SafteyFaults.PLCStates.Good)
        SafteyFaults.PLCSafeStates.testStates1[0]=SafteyFaults.PLCStates.Bad;
        else
        SafteyFaults.PLCSafeStates.testStates1[0] = SafteyFaults.PLCStates.Good;

    }
```

Comment: Apparently, you never initialize the array (like `testStates1 = new PLCStates[20];`). This will however still not solve your problem, as no event is fired when you set an array element, e.g `testStates1[0] = PLCStates.Good;`. I'd suggest to create a class with a `State` property, which implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to notify about property changes. Then create a collection of instances of this class to hold multiple states.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens, lots of good clues there. My only question is about instances: I thought using `static` meant I wasn't using instances (I guess that's the real crux of this question: I'm tripping over using `static` in this context).

Comment: I'm on the wrong path here- started doing what you suggested, @Clemens, and ran into `array elements cannot be of a static type`. I know there has to be a way to do this without a mountain of boilerplate code, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Something like `public static ObservableCollection<PLCStateWrapper> TestStates1 { get; set; }` should work well, where PLCStateWrapper has a property of type PLCStates.